# Evaluation of an Integral in Vector Analysis

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I'm trying to calculate an individual probability $P(\hat{a})$ from a joint probability $P(\hat{a},\hat{b})$ in a physics application, where $\hat{a},\hat{b}$ are unit vectors.

I need to evaluate the following integral:

$P(\hat{a})=\int P(\hat{a},\hat{b}) d\hat{b}$

The value of the joint probability is $P(\hat{a},\hat{b})=\frac{1}{4}[1+\hat{a}\cdot\hat{b}]=\frac{1}{4}[1+\cos\theta_{ab}]$.

I'm not really sure how to begin dealing with this integral.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this in 2D or 3D?

Comment: Sorry, 3D. It's a measurable quantity in the lab.